# Use PdfReport.Core in a WEB-API .NET CORE 2

Tags: c#, pdf, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

I am looking into [PdfReport.Core](https://github.com/VahidN/PdfReport.Core) and have been asked to let our .NET CORE 2.0 WEB-API return a PDF to the calling client. The client would be any https caller like a ajax or mvc client.
Below is a bit of the code I am using.  I am using swashbuckle to test the api, which looks like it is returning the report but when I try to open in a PDF viewer it says it is curropted.  I am thinking I am not actually outputting the actual PDF to the stream, suggestions?

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/v1/pdf")]
    public FileResult GetPDF()
    {

            var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
            InMemoryPdfReport.CreateStreamingPdfReport(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, outputStream);
            outputStream.Position = 0;
            return new FileStreamResult(outputStream, "application/pdf")
            {
                FileDownloadName = "report.pdf"
            };


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that particular library, but generally speaking with streams, file corruption is a result of either 1) the write not being flushed or 2) incorrect positioning within the stream.

Since, you've set the position back to zero, I'm guessing the problem is that your write isn't being flushed correctly. Essentially, when you write to a stream, the data is not necessarily "complete" in the stream. Sometimes writes are queued to more efficiently write in batches. Sometimes, there's cleanup tasks a particular stream writer needs to complete to "finalize" everything. For example, with a format like PDF, end matter may need to be appended to the bytes, particular to the format. A stream writer that is writing PDF would take care of this in a flush operation, since it cannot be completed until all writing is done.

Long and short, review the documentation of the library. In particular, look for any method/process that deals with "flushing". That's most likely what your missing.